# Sending and displaying images from Adonis V4.1

Tags: javascript, backend, adonis.js

How can I send an image from a React App to Adonis, “save” it on the database, and when needed to fetch it to use in the front-end?
Right now, I was only successful in processing an image via Postman, my code would be like this:

```js
const image = request.file('photo', {
  types: ['image'],
  size: '2mb',
});

await image.move(Helpers.tmpPath('uploads'), {
  name: `${Date.now()}-${image.clientName}`,
});

if (image.status !== 'moved') {
  return image.error;
}

/////

const data = {
  username,
  email,
  role,
  photo: image.fileName,
  password,
  access: 1,
};

const user = await User.create(data);
```

In the first part, I process the image move it to tmp inside the backend, on the next part I use `image.fileName` and create a User.

And when I need to fetch my user list, I do it like this:

```js
const colaboradoresList = await Database.raw(
  'select * from colaboradores where access = 1'
);
const userList = colaboradoresList[0];
userList.map((i) => (i.url = Helpers.tmpPath(`uploads/${i.photo}`)));
```

But as you can tell, `Helpers.tmpPath('uploads/${i.photo}'))` will return the local path to the current image, and I cannot display it on React since I need to use the public folder or download it and import.

Is there a way to do it locally, or the only way would be to create an AWS and use `Drive.getUrl()` to create a URL and send back to my front end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the UI cannot display local files, you need to expose a public url for the image. You have two options depending of the scope of this application

1. If you plan to run this as a professional app, I would highly suggest to use something like AWS S3 to store images.
2. Otherwise you can probably get away with setting up a route for the React UI to query. Something like `/api/image/:id` could return the binary or base64 encoded data of the image, which React could then display.

Comment: I forgot about this, I've found a way to make it work the way I wanted to

Comment: I've added my solution to the answers, but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
await image.move(Helpers.tmpPath('uploads'), {
  name: `${Date.now()}-${image.clientName}`,
});
```

I use:

```
await image.move(Helpers.publicPath('uploads'),
{name: `${Date.now()}-${image.clientName}`})
```

For that you will need to change the folders to make it store correctly:
[image: folder formation]

And then send to the front-end `url = '/uploads/${i.photo}'`, where `i.photo` is the file name, so I can concatenate in React like so `apiBase + url`.
The result being your `apiUrl + your file path` that should be on public folder:
[image: result]

Comment: hey, are ur Adonis set up as Api or Web ?

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN It was a while since I've touched this project, but I'm pretty sure the adonis was only used as an API.